# Is there a Javascript presentation / slides script, to integrate on a Web App?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, javascript-framework

I´ve been searching for a Simple version of an OnLine Presentation Script like 280slides, Prezentit, etc. to integrate on my Web Application which will use a registered user environment.

I don´t mind if is based on commercial license, but haven´t find an option, all of them seem to be stand alone web service.

it just needs...

- slides list
- text, images and shaped elements(stars, arrows, etc)
- simple element manipulation (drag, size, arrange, delete)
- presentation controls(stop, play, next...)
- image background option

So far it all points I would need to develop something myself, I guess with a JS framework like capuccino.

thank you

Comment: Have you looked at [Eric Meyer's S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/)? Might be able to wrap editing functions around that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple wordpress plugin which uses jquery to create the simple slideshow functionality. You can use it as a jquery plugin if you want.

Check out the [Demo](http://www.innovativephp.com/ipage-slides) and see it contains what you want.

simple element manipulation (drag, size, arrange, delete) is not currently added

Comment: thank you, I´ll take it for consideration, actually, when I read that it didn´t include drag, arrange etc, it made me think of an option of redefining how Presentations are made, in case I end up developing something myself.